# The Entity Framework 4.0 and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, complextype, multiple-resultsets

How to get **multiple result sets** using **Entity Data Framework** from SQL Server?

For example, I need to get the **Customer's personal** and **account details** from a **Stored Procedure** that contains following queries

```
SELECT CustomerID,Name,Address FROM Customers
go
SELECT CustomerID,AccountCode FROM CustomerAccounts
```

But when I create ComplexType, only the first statement is executed.

Please help.......

Comment: what have you tried, have you seen post like this and tried out? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

Comment: Dear Imran thanks for your quick reply. But its not easy as creating a normal Complex Type. I want to handle this in so many scenarios so I need a much more interactive way rather than writing so much of code everytime.